# How do I go about this relationship?

Tags: sql, powerdesigner

novice in SQL here.

I've got this relationship:

[image: relationship]

Teams have references to all 5 members and each player has reference to his team. Now, should I also make teamPlayer1,2,... a FK of PLAYERS entity? Cause so far I've only worked with relationships where simply one attribute corresponded to another, not five to one. Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: If you want to guarantee referential integrity then you should have a FK relationship between each of the teamPlayer columns and the playerId in the Players table.

Comment: Not sure how to go about this in my modelling software. All I can do is have 1-1 1-many many-1 many-many relationships. How to achieve this?

Comment: You need to add more context (or tags). What is your modelling software? what is your DB?

Comment: I'm working with PowerDesigner first with a conceptual model and then just auto export it to physical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

teamPlayer1–5 are redundant and should be removed. You can reconstruct the list of players by means of a join. If you want to allow only five players per team, augment PLAYERS with `teamMember int, UNIQUE(teamId, teamMember), CHECK(teamMember between 0 and 4)`.

Correction: You can reconstruct players per team without a join, since the required information is all in the PLAYERS table.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you create three tables: `teams`, `players`, `team_players`.

`Teams`

```
create table teams (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    teamname varchar(100) not null,
    country varchar(100) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

`Players`

```
create table players (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    firstname varchar(100) not null,
    lastname varchar(100) not null,
    nickname varchar(100),
    country varchar(100) not null,
    fieldposition varchar(100), -- can be an int FK to a fieldpositions table
    debutdate date,
    primary key (id)
);
```

`Team_players`

```
create table team_players (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    teamid int not null,
    playerid int not null,
    primary key (id),
    constraint uk_team_players_rel unique (teamid, playerid),
    constraint fk_team_players_teamid foreign key (teamid) references teams (id),
    constraint fk_team_players_playerid foreign key (playerid) references players (id)
);
```

Example (MySQL): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c4ff8